# Corona SDK: Want to change scene when audio ends. (not working)

Tags: audio, mobile, lua, coronasdk, playsound

So I have this set up. The sound works. The endGame function also works if the function is called directly, in the `scene:create( event )`.
But when I call the function from the onComplete method in the sound, the function triggers, but the i get this message "attempted to call a nil value" after the sound stops playing.

```
media.playSound( quotepath, {onComplete = endGame } )
```

the function:

```
function endGame()
composer.gotoScene( "scenes.gameover", "fade", 500 )
end
```

Comment: can you post the console log error?

Comment: Runtime error
attempt to call a nil value

Answer (score 1):

This how the syntax should be of,

```
 local onComplete

 onComplete = function(event)
    print( "sound play ended" )

end

media.playSound( "song1.mp3", onComplete )
```

Comment: except playSound isn't the only thing with the onComplete attribute. So if that is the syntax, it's horrible syntax. lol

Comment: that's odd, it worked. The way I was doing it was also labeled as the syntax. wounder why this method works. Why is lua so illogical. lol